# Stop Button in Ionic Text to Speech

Tags: ionic-framework, audio, text-to-speech

in Ionic I managed to make a program with the tts plugin that reproduces the text that I write in an input, but so far I have not been able to implement a button that stops the audio that is played, I would appreciate a lot if you help me.
How do I make a class that stops the audio?

This is my .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TextToSpeech } from '@ionic-native/text-to-speech/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-textvoice',
  templateUrl: './textvoice.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./textvoice.page.scss'],
})

export class TextvoicePage {
  
  text: string;
  locale: string;
  copyText: string="";
  pasteText: string="";

  constructor ( private tts: TextToSpeech, public clipboard: Clipboard) {
    this.text= '';
    this.locale= 'es-MX';
  }

  playText (){
    this.tts.speak({
      text: this.text,
      locale: this.locale
    })
    .then((res) => console.log (res))
    .catch((err) => console.log (err));
  }

    stop(){
  
  }
```

This is my html:

```html
 
<ion-content>

 <ion-button fill="solid" color="light" expand="block" (click)="playText()"><ion-icon name="play-outline"></ion-icon>
    A texto
  </ion-button>

  <ion-button fill="solid" color="light" expand="block" (click)="stop()"><ion-icon name="stop-outline"></ion-icon>
    Detener audio
  </ion-button>
 
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Have you tried the [well-documented `stop()` method](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/text-to-speech/#stop)?

Comment: in this case how would it be used?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what *specifically* you're confused on? All you have to do in this scenario is to call the `stop()` method on your instance of the `TextToSpeech` object, similar to how you've called the `speak` method in your class's `playText()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to [the documentation for `@ionic-native/TextToSpeech`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/text-to-speech/#stop) as it clearly outlines that `stop()` is used for this exact purpose.

In your specific scenario, your instance of `TextToSpeech` is available in the `this.tts` variable. As such you can invoke `stop()` by simply calling it on this object within your class's method:

```
stop(){
    this.tts.stop();
}
```

Comment: I have tried it with that method but it just ignores it and it doesn't work for me

Comment: That is pertinent information you should include in your question; I encourage you to edit it to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I already managed to solve, I put this code and when giving it stop if the code worked

```html
    stop(){
      this.tts.speak("")
  }
```